# How can I join 2 XML in 1 XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have two `.xml` files which need to be joined

The first file is `Song.xml` as the following:

```
<Songs>
  <Song>
    <SongID>1</SongID>
    <SongName>We dont talk anymore</SongName>
    <Author>M-TP</Author>
    <UploadBy>admin</UploadBy>
    <GerneCode>1</GerneCode>
  </Song>
</Songs>
```

and the Gerne.xml which generate from a schema

```
<ns2:gernes xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/playlist" xmlns:ns2="https://xml.netbeans.org/schema/genses">
    <ns2:gerne>
        <GerneCode>1</GerneCode>
        <GerneName>Pop</GerneName>        
        <Image>img-pop.jpg</Image>
    </ns2:gerne>
</ns2:gerne>
```

I want to join these `.xml` files inside a `XSL`, to which will add the GerneName for every Song that match the GerneName inside the `Gerne.xml`.

The result im trying to get should be like this:

```
<Songs>
      <Song>
        <SongID>1</SongID>
        <SongName>We dont talk anymore</SongName>
        <Author>M-TP</Author>
        <UploadBy>admin</UploadBy>
        <GerneName>Pop</GerneName>
        <GerneCode>1</GerneCode>
      </Song>
</Songs>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Any e.g or keywords what should I look up for this problem?

Comment: To get started, read the `Gerne.xml` using [document](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp) function , get the `GerneCode`, `GerneName` , see if `GerneCode` matches the current element's `GerneCode` in `Songs.xml` and copy the `GerneCode`, `GerneName` under your current element in `Songs.xml`. You can use [XpathFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html) for xpath expressions and TransformerFactory , see : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html) for transforming your xml once you have the xsl.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are limited to XSLT 1.0, you can do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:pl="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/playlist"
xmlns:ns2="https://xml.netbeans.org/schema/genses"
exclude-result-prefixes="pl ns2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="lookup-path" select="'Gerne.xml'" />
<xsl:key name="genre" match="ns2:gerne" use="pl:GerneCode" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GerneCode">
    <xsl:variable name="code" select="." />
    <!-- switch context to the other file -->
    <xsl:for-each select="document($lookup-path)">
        <GerneCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('genre', $code)/pl:GerneName" />
        </GerneCode>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming you are telling your XSLT processor to process the `Song.xml` file, and passing the path to the `Gerne.xml` file as a parameter.

Note that the `Gerne.xml` document you have posted is not well-formed XML (no `</ns2:gernes>` closing tag).

---

BTW, the correct term is "genre" - not "gerne" or "gense".

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. Sorry for my bad English, Im having problem with my vocabulary.